# iPhone Setting A Background Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, ios4

I want to use an image as a background for my application.  I want the buttons to be over the image.  How is this accomplished?  Everytime I use image view it covers up the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image view should cover your buttons unless you are placing it higher in the list of subviews. Make sure your image view subview is added first and the buttons (and all other views) will be displayed on top of it.
Are you doing this in Interface Builder or manually in code?

Comment: I was using Interface Builder, trying to get an outline of the application before implemented any code.

Comment: Gotcha, select your image view in IB and from the IB menu select Layout -> Send to Back OR Send Backwards. This will move your image view back in the subview stack. The other option is to move your buttons forward.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using UIView's sendSubviewToBack method:

```
UIImageView view = / init view */;
// some additional code here
mainView.addSubview(view);
// add buttons, etc...
mainView.sendSubviewToBack(view);
```